# Solutions from google for this services?

Tags: gmail, ssl-certificate, google-workspace, google-developers-console

I am looking to change my providers and trying to move all under google but I don't find this information

1) for sms gateway google have any solution ? I curently use clickatell.com
2) for email providers google can offer something to send 1 milion emails per month ?
3) for ssl certificates i use leaderssl.com .  Does google offer this ssl certifiactes ?
4) Does google offer any push notifications service for browsers? Simulate with pushengage.com ?
5) can I get from google an alternative of http://ip-api.com/  ?

I moved rest of services and for this services I am not sure if google have any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

1. for sms gateway google have any solution?

- Google has a service related to Gmail, SMS with Gmail, although the documentation seems to be more related to a personal usage than a massive one. I believe you can request more information stating in this [page](https://web.archive.org/web/20170907115719/https://www.google.com/intl/en_gh/mail/help/sms/chat.html).

2. for email providers google can offer something to send 1 million emails per month?

- In Google Cloud Platform you could setup and use ['SendGrid, Mailgun, or Mailjet'](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/#choosing_an_email_service_to_use) for mailing, but I believe also you could research if [Gsuite](https://workspace.google.com/intl/en_ie/features/) could be a better fit for you [3](https://workspace.google.com/intl/en_ie/features/).

3. for ssl certificates I use leaderssl.com . Does google offer this ssl certificates?

- No, Google does not offer SSL certificates.

4. Does google offer any push notifications service for browsers? Simulate with pushengage.com ?

- You could check in this Google developers Web Fundamentals, [Introduction to Push Notifications](https://web.dev/notifications/) section if this could work for you.

5. can I get from google an alternative of http://ip-api.com/? Not that I know.